# How can I use java libraries for a standalone application (MATLAB, MacOs)

Tags: java, macos, matlab, compiler-errors, matlab-app-designer

I am having trouble using java libraries with my standalone application (developed with Application compiler for Matlab 2019).

I am using the XLWRITE command to create excel files on MacOs. For that reason, I needed to import java .jar files. My code works fine when I use AppDesigner but when I try to compile the aplication, it doesn't work anymore...

```
j1= 'poi-3.8-20120326.jar';
full_j1=fullfile(pathname,j1);
javaaddpath(full_j1);
import poi-3.8-20120326.*;
```

I wanted to use that kind of code to import the java files and use the XLWRITE command...

Could you help me solve this problem?

Thank you :)

Comment: The syntax you are using here is different from the syntax in the documentation/examples for xlwrite. In particular, the java classes are loaded in the background by xlwrite.m so you shouldn't have to. What is the specific error message (in console debug) you get when trying to run xlwrite?

Comment: I tried the one used in the example on mathworks and it doesn't work either...  There isn't any error message, when I used Appdesigner it worked well and once I compiled the application (to make it function without MATLAB) it doesn't anymore...